# Real centrally-symmetric plane algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a reference regarding the topology of real centrally-symmetric plane algebraic curves. By this I mean the curves defined by
$$
P(x,y)=0,
$$
where $P$ is a degree $m$ polynomial, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and
$$
P(-x,-y)=-P(x,y).
$$

I would be very grateful for any reference or any equivalent reformulation in more general terms.